# How do I use React-Native to authorize the Spotify API?

Tags: javascript, api, react-native, spotify

I am attempting to use React-Native to call and log into Spotify, but I cannot figure out how to properly call the API to open the URL in my "GET" request. This is the function I am calling when a 'Log In' button is pushed:

```
function fetchSpotifyAuthorization(){
fetch(AUTHORIZE_API_CALL_URL)
  .then(response => {
      console.log(response);
      return {
      authCode: response.code,
      authState: response.state,
      };
  })
  .catch ( error => {console.error(error);});

    fetchSpotifyRefreshToken();
}

function fetchSpotifyRefreshToken(){
    fetch('https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token/', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Basic ' + client_id_secret_base64,
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        grant_type: 'authorization_code',
        code: authCode,
        redirect_uri: redirect_uri,
      }),
    })
    .then (response => response.json())
    .then(responseJSON => {
        return {
        access_token: responseJSON.access_token,
        token_type: responseJSON.token_type,
        scope: responseJSON.scope,
        expires_in: responseJSON.expires_in,
        refresh_token: responseJSON.refresh_token
        };
    })
}
```

Please help, I have been searching for hours and every Github module for this authorization process is either outdated/deprecated, or only usable with XCode which I cannot use.